# how to implement geo location through Apigee

Tags: geolocation, apigee, usergrid, apigee-baas

I'm doing an sample eCommerce webpage where I have the following collections in BaaS-- customer address(zip code) and store address(zip code along with latitude & longitude). So in webpage when customer clicks "check nearest stores".

Then the google maps api should take customers zipcode and store zipcode as input and find which store is nearest to him(say in XXX miles radius). [This is my understanding and may not be an accurate way to do, kindly suggest any better ways to do]

Geolocation capability in Apigee BaaS is just about the storage and querying aspects of it.
I'm actually confused about how to start this and do it through Apigee.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the documents here: http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/geolocation.

Basically, on any entity you can have a 'location' attribute and then query as follows:

```
select * where location within {d} of {latitude}, {longitude}
```